# Not able to include a widget in the scaffold due to missing preferred size constraint?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-appbar

Getting the following error when implementing my appbar with Flutter. I can include it elsewhere in the children array of the body Stack, just not with the appBar: under Scaffold.

> The argument type 'Widget' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'PreferredSizeWidget?'.

I can add the Widget like this and it works, but not like this and I'm trying to figure out why I can't include my appbar() widget in this manner.

This works ok

```
class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Welcome"),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
```

This does not, though by rights it should as it is merely returning the AppBar when called. Wrapping it in a PreferredSize() like so also does not work.

This doesn't work

```
Widget appBar() {
  return PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(100),
        child: Container(color: Colors.transparent, child: AppBar(
    title: const Text("Welcome"),
    centerTitle: true,
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    elevation: 0.0,
  )));
}
```

This doesn't work

```
Widget appBar() {
  return AppBar(
    title: const Text("Welcome"),
    centerTitle: true,
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    elevation: 0.0,
  );
}
```

Including appBar() below in the Scaffold

```
class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: appBar(),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the return type widget to `PreferredSize`.

```dart
  PreferredSize appBar() {
    return PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(100),
        child: Container(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child: AppBar(
              title: const Text("Welcome"),
              centerTitle: true,
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              elevation: 0.0,
            )));
  }
```

Also, can be done like `appBar: appBar() as PreferredSize` but better to do change return type,

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in the return type. appBar in scaffold will require a PreferredSize widget.. You can mark the return like this

```
AppBar appBar() {
  return AppBar(
    title: const Text("Welcome"),
    centerTitle: true,
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    elevation: 0.0,
  );
}
```